# Como usar esc para parar um programa no meio de sua execução em C?

Tags: c

Gostaria de fazer o programa parar ao pressionar ESC em qualquer momento, como seria possível?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com o uso da função `getch` você consegue pegar o carácter que foi digitado no console, que nesse caso o número 27 representa o ESC do teclado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char opcao;
    while(opcao != 27)
    {
        printf("\n\n\nEscolha uma opcao:\n");

        printf("<esc> para sair\n\n");

        opcao = getch();

        if (opcao != 27)
        {
            printf("Voce nao apertou ESC\n\n");
        }     
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nota adicional: [A `conio.h` é platform-dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792317/why-cant-i-find-conio-h-on-linux).

Comment: Como eu faria pra getch ser "opcional"? Se eu não apertar nada, ele simplesmente executa a próxima função. Caso eu aperte, ele aborta o programa em qualquer parte dele. Obrigado